# Edge from node to another edge visjs Angular 4

Tags: angular, vis.js, vis.js-network

I'm using Vis.js for drawing a graph with Angular4 and trying to draw an edge `{ from : node , to : edge , arrows : 'to'}`. Giving nodeid and edgeid respectively. But it is not pointing to the edge. Its still pointing to node. How to make edge point to another edge?
I want something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can't do this directly, vis.js's model is straight-forward: edges connect nodes. However, you can create a hidden node like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/tjyvLbns/45/):

```
var nodes = new vis.DataSet([
     {id:1,label:"from", x:0,  y:0}
    ,{id:2,x:0,  y:100, hidden:true}
    ,{id:3,label:"intercept", x:100,y:100}
    ,{id:4,label:"to", x:0,  y:200}
]);
var edges = new vis.DataSet([
     {from:1, to:2}
    ,{from:2, to:3, arrows:"from"}
    ,{from:2, to:4, arrows:"to"}
]);
```

to get this:

[image]